# JavaScript: How to format a str.replace with ReactDOMServer.renderToString, using a captured element as a prop

Tags: javascript, regex, reactjs, render-to-string, react-dom-server

I am trying to apply this regex

```js
str.replace(/<L href=(.*?)>(.*?)<\/L>/g, ReactDOMServer.renderToString(<L href={$1}>$1</L>))
```

But it doesn't recognize the `$1` that is in the `href={$1}` (says it is not defined), while it does appear in the second place and it shows it is correctly captured

How can I write it?

*So the problem is not with the regex, but with how can I use the captured variable as a parameter form the component

---

Maybe something like this?

```
($1, $2) => ReactDOMServer.renderToString(<L href={$1}>$1</L>)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can be workarounded by not capturing the comas

```
str.replace(/<L href="(.*?)">(.*?)<\/L>/g, ReactDOMServer.renderToString(<L href="$1">$1</L>))
```

But isn't there a better way?